# Why does this text bypass the RegEx scanning?

Tags: regex, security

A scammer is mass messaging our users using this form of messages (   . () ***-***    .      ℙ.
ℍ    ,                        
)

My questions:

1. Why does the message text look like that? Is that a font?
2. How does this kind of text bypass the manual RegEx text scanning? We do scan every message to catch any suspicious message.

Comment: Obligatory link: *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)*

Comment: @mickmackusa OP isn't asking why the hackers chose a font, but why the characters look the way they do, which is a technical reason, not an opinion.

Comment: You should probably include some examples of your regexes that this passes to clarify why this is in fact a programming related question.

Comment: Scanning in what programming language (and/or other context)? Capabilities [vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary#Phrase).

Comment: Related: *[List of visually similar characters, for detecting spoofing and social engineering attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128286)*, *[Why do so many spam emails lately contain a lot of Unicode characters?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214306)*, *[How to defend against homograph attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182680)*, and *[Is there a dictionary of visibly similar Unicode characters for Spam processing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36257)*,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters they used,  (Mathematical Double Struck A (U+1D538)) -  (Mathematical Double Struck z (U+1D56B)) are part of the Unicode characters, not a separate font.

If you did not think about special Unicode characters when writing your regular expressions then they will not catch those because a simple `/\w/` will not match any of those unless you also specify to explicitly match Unicode (often with the flag `/u` at the end of the expression).

Similarly `/A/` will not match `""` simply because they are different characters and that pattern only matches that specific character.

In order to not have to think about every possible way to represent a similar looking character, you can [normalize your Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) before running your regular expressions on them. That way, a consistent representation is guaranteed and you'll have a much easier time to write expressions that match a much wider range of texts.